# get the username value of user in FOSuserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a many to many entity relationship, User and Project
The User entity has only one field, the id field since it is extending the FOsUserBundle. I understand that to access the current logged in users by calling the container

```
$user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

But that's not the case.A project has many users saved in a database.Now I can access it by using a twig loop

```
 users_projects//a many to many table
 project_id   user_id
 3             1
 3             2

<td>{% for user in project.users %}{{ user.id}}{% endfor %}</td>

outputs 1,2
```

The user entity has no getUsername method as it has only one id field.How would you display the username instead of an i.d?

**Update**

Already solved this.I dont really sure if its the proper way .In ProjectType, I added this

```
->add('users', 'entity', array(
          'class' => 'UserBundle:User',
          'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
              return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                  ->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');
          },
          'expanded' => true,
          'multiple' => true
        ))
```

With this set up

```
 <td>
      {% for user in entity.users %}
          {{ user.username }}
           {% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
 </td>
```

Now works.Just don't forget to include

```
  use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
```

In FormType, else it will throw an error something like

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to.....must be an instance of \EmployeeBundle\Form\EntityRepository, instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository given

Comment: Curious, the exemple class in FOSUserBundle has a getUsername() method at line 221 https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/User.php

Comment: I already solved this